# The ’Rakers/ Hayley’s refrences

Tags: british-english, reference, irish-english

this passage is from Jerusalem by Jez Butterworth, what Hayley’s referring to? and where is The ’Rakers?

JOHNNY. Serves you right. Why don’t you fuck off home like
the rest of ’em. Stop round Hayley’s, you don’t wanna go
home…

JOHNNY collects an axe from the porch. He goes over to a
pile of logs to the side of the trailer. He takes one, puts it on
a stump.

LEE. Here, Tanya. You seen Phaedra?

TANYA. What?

LEE. Phaedra. Her mum said she ain’t been home for days.

JOHNNY splits a log.

TANYA. I ain’t seen her all week, mate.

PEA. Who’s that?

LEE. Phaedra? She ain’t been home.

PEA. Last time I saw Phaedra, right, was… fancy-dress night.

Fancy-dress night at The ’Rakers.

TANYA. That doorman is a wanker.

GINGER. Why?

TANYA. He is. He’s such a tuss.

GINGER. What happened?

PEA. She’d made her own costume, right, made a real effort,
stitching, sequins, and she shows up at The ’Rakers and the
fucking doorman turns her away.

Comment: My guess would be that it's a pub. The apostrophe suggests that a syllable has been dropped, so it may be short for 'The Moonrakers' (from an old tale about people trying to rake the reflection of the moon out of a pond). _Fancy-dress night_ will be an event where people turn up in costume.

Comment: `Hayley's` is Hayley's home. The leading apostrophe in `’Rakers` tells us it is a contraction. It has a doorman, we know, and is probably a nightclub or bar. Very few English words end in `rakers`, a common one being `moonrakers`. A quick Google for "Jez Butterworth Jerusalem rakers" shows that The Moonrakers is a real pub in Pewsey, Wiltshire, that Butterworth drank in. Local reviewers of the play have pointed out that they call it "Moonies", and not 'Rakers.